# Сайт отображение местоположения android в реальном времени

Tags: php, python

У меня есть простое приложение на андроид, которое, например, каждую минуту отправляет координаты местоположения на сервер (простой php или python сайт). Там я их принимаю, и чисто ради интереса записываю в базу. Все вроде работает.

Теперь хочу сделать на сайте карту, на которой бы в реальном времени было видно расположение андроид устройства.
Что для этого нужно и как приступить к этому? кто знает, поделитесь опытом

Примером может быть life360 или [этот сайт](https://www.locationof.com/demo/map/).
Но мне для начала не нужен никакой доп. функционал. Местоположение просто отображать маркером на карте google в реальном времени.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую следующую связку:

- postgreSQL+postGIS - хранение и обработка географических данных;
- Openstreetmap - карты в качестве подложки (нет таких ограничений на использование, как у карт Яндекса или Гугла, например);
- Leaflet - для отображения данных;

На сайте [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) есть примеры работы с данными и множество плагинов, в т.ч. и [leaflet-realtime](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime) ([демо](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-realtime/))

На сервере Вам надо будет формировать данные (удобно, например, использовать формат geoJson), а с помощью Leaflet отображать подложку и Ваши данные. Поле для творчества огромное, ограничено только Вашей фантазией и знанием javascript :)